# Salesforce Apex increase coverage test

Tags: unit-testing, boolean, code-coverage, apex-code

My test coverage is up to 66%, how can I increase?
I do not know how to acces or use the **alerta** variable into the test class, I want to increase the test covergae from 66% to atleast 75% or even more

**Apex class:**

```
public static Boolean getContacto (String contactId) {
    Boolean alerta = false;
    if(String.isNotBlank(contactId) && String.isNotEmpty(contactId)){
        Contact contacto =[SELECT Id, UniqueId_Status__c, UniqueId__c from Contact where Id =: contactId and Country__c = 'CHILE'];
        
        if(contacto.UniqueId__c == null && (contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M2' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M3' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M4' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R2' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R3' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R4')){
            alerta = true;
        }else
        if(contacto.UniqueId__c != null && (contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M2' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M3' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'M4' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R2' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R3' || contacto.UniqueId_Status__c == 'R4')){
            alerta = true;   
        }else
        if(contacto.UniqueId__c != null && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'M2' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'M3' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'M4' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'R2' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'R3' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'R4' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != 'D1' && contacto.UniqueId_Status__c != null){
            alerta = true;   
        }
    }        
    return alerta;
}
```

**TestClass:**

```
@isTest public class ATCL_BloquearContactoTest {    @IsTest
    static void bloqueaContactoTest(){
        Contact contactos = new Contact();
        
        contactos.FirstName = 'Amanda';
        contactos.LastName = 'testing';
        contactos.UniqueId_Status__c = 'M1';
        contactos.Country__c = 'CHILE';
        insert contactos;
        
        Test.startTest();
        ATCL_BloquearContactoCTRL.getContacto(contactos.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    } }
```

I do **not** Know how to coverage **alerta** variable [image]

Thanks Juan

Answer (score 0):

The low key is to reckon those **ifs** as diferent scenarios.
To achive those diferente scenarios you must add the new values into the test class to eventually pass the **ifs** sentences. Every scenrio should be resolve with a difrent @istest method:

```
public class ATCL_BloquearContactoTest {
@IsTest
static void bloqueaContactoTestNull(){
    Contact contactos = new Contact();
    
    contactos.FirstName = 'Amanda';
    contactos.LastName = 'testing';
    contactos.UniqueId__c = null;//== null
    contactos.UniqueId_Status__c = 'M2';//like M_ || R_
    contactos.Country__c = 'CHILE';
    insert contactos;
    
    Test.startTest();
    ATCL_BloquearContactoCTRL.getContacto(contactos.Id);
    Test.stopTest();

}
@IsTest
static void bloqueaContactoTestNotNull(){
    Contact contactos = new Contact();
    
    contactos.FirstName = 'Amanda';
    contactos.LastName = 'testing';
    contactos.UniqueId__c = '21354689';//!= null
    contactos.UniqueId_Status__c = 'M2';//like M_ || R_
    contactos.Country__c = 'CHILE';
    insert contactos;
    
    Test.startTest();
    ATCL_BloquearContactoCTRL.getContacto(contactos.Id);
    Test.stopTest();

}
@IsTest
static void bloqueaContactoTestNotNullNotNull(){
    Contact contactos = new Contact();
    
    contactos.FirstName = 'Amanda';
    contactos.LastName = 'testing';
    contactos.UniqueId__c = '21354689';//!= null
    contactos.UniqueId_Status__c = '0';//!(like  M_ || R_)
    contactos.Country__c = 'CHILE';
    insert contactos;
    
    Test.startTest();
    ATCL_BloquearContactoCTRL.getContacto(contactos.Id);
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

}

Bye